# ethers sendTransaction times out

Tags: remix, ether, ethers.js, javascript

I am using Remix IDE with the Remix VM (Shanghai) environment.

In a Javascript unit test, I would like to send Ether from the main account to another account. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
// Right click on the script name and hit "Run" to execute
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
describe("Ether transaction", function () {
  it("test transaction", async function () {
    let [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
    let balance = (await owner.getBalance()).toBigInt();
    console.log(`Current balance is: ${balance}`);
    let value = ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0");
    expect(balance).to.be.at.least(value);
    let recipient = "<another address>";
    console.log(`Sending some ETH to recipient ${recipient}`);
    await owner.sendTransaction({
        "to": recipient,
        "value": value
    });
    let newBalance = (await owner.getBalance()).toBigInt();
    console.log(`New balance is: ${newBalance}`);
    expect(newBalance - balance).to.be(value);
  });
});
```

But the sendTransaction function hangs until it times out. In the console I see this error message:

```
✘ test transaction (50738 ms)
  Message: Timeout of 50000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Why does sendTransaction not work?

Comment: Btw, deploying a contract with an initial balance works fine:
`await SomeContract.deploy({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1")});`

Answer (score 0):

This snippet appears to host a number of asynchrony's functions, make sure to resolve them. If your getting unexpected, potentially null or undefined, values its most likely because your using async functions and don't resolve 'await' uses.

Comment: How would you do it instead of await owner.sendTransaction? Until this point, everything works fine.

Comment: `const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
        const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(wallet.address);
        const tx = { ...transaction, nonce };
        
        const txResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction);
        console.log(txResponse);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};`

Comment: this code worked for me. it could also be possible that you have no RPC accsess.